# Hilbert Coeficients; Multiplicity

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, graded-rings, graded-modules

Let $R$ be a graded ring and $M$ a graded $R$-module. An element $x\in R_{l}$ is said to be *superficial* for $M$ if $(0:_{M} x)_{n}=0$ for all but finitely many $n$.

Let $M$ be a finite generated $R$-module of positive dimension and $x\in R_{+}$ a superficial element for $M$. If $\dim(M)>1$ prove that $e(M/xM)=\deg(x)e(M)$, where $e(M)$ is the first coefficient of Hilbert polynomial.

Comment: This is Exercise 7.10 from Marley notes "Graded Rings and Modules". Since it's probably a homework I'll give you only a hint: use the exact sequence $0\to(0:_Mx)(-l)\to M(-l)\stackrel{x\cdot}\to M\to M/xM\to 0$, and Hilbert series.

Comment: I wonder how can it be like that. Because $e(X)$ depends on the cofficients of $g(t)$ in $g(t)/(1-t)^{d}$, but we can not control what is it. How can we caculate it?

Comment: @Soulostar Try to prove the claim (eventually by using my hint) and convince yourself.